# Is the highest weight constructed irreducible representiation of a Lie Algebra unique?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In Georgis book I stumbled across the sentence:
"It is true that every irreducible representation is finite dimensional and equivalent to one of the constructions we found with the highest weight construction."
Since there can be in-equivalent irreducible representations that means that the highest weight constructed irreducible representation of a Lie Algebra is not unique, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, the claim is wrong.

There are examples of irreducible representations which are infinite dimensional:
Let $V$ be any $\mathbb{C}$ vector space for which  a basis of the form $(e_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ can be written. 
Let's look at the lie Algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2\mathbb{C}$ with the 
(usual) basis $\{H,X,Y\}$, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)). Let $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. Define a representation 
$$\pi: \mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$$ 
by setting:
 $$\pi(H)e_k=(t-2k)e_k, \quad \pi(Y)e_k=(k+1)e_{k+1}, \quad \pi(X)e_k=(t-k+1)e_{k-1} \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Now, the [linear hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of $\{e_k\}_{k < 0}$, call it $V_{-}$, is an invariant subspace of $V$ (under the given action) and is, indeed, irreducible.

Edit: As for your actual question: If we restrict ourselfs to the finite dimensional case and only look at representations of (complex) semisimple Lie Algebras the [theorem of highest weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_of_the_highest_weight) states that the highest weight does determine the representation (up to equivalence), in general there can be irreducible inequvalent representations on the same vector space (if $t-t' \notin 2 \mathbb Z$, we get two inequivalent represntations on $V_{-}$).

Comment: I do not know a reference for this (I know the fact from a worked exercise). If anyone does know one, I'd be very grateful if it could be edited into my answer or written as a comment (or answer)! Otherwise I'd try my best to write a proof here, but I don't have the time for that right now...

Comment: Ok, he is talking about about it in the context of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. For that his claim holds by the Peter-Weyl theorem, right?  Your example $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C}$ is its complexification, which is no longer compact so the Peter-Weyl theorem doesn't apply anymore, right?

Comment: Be careful: The Peter Weyl theorem does apply for compact $groups$, and for this, it holds. If you furthermore restrict yourself only to those representations which are induced by Group Representations (by means of their differential) then it is true. In general, not every representation of a Lie Algebra is induced by that of it's Lie Group. In the finite dimensional case, this holds if the Group at hand is simply connected (as is $SU(2)$ -this is known as Lie's second theorem). I do not know though, if this still holds if we allow infinite dimensional representations.

Comment: but isn't $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ again a compact group?

Comment: No, it is a Lie $Algebra$. This is of course a Group with respect to addition, but since it's a vector space (of dimension $>0$), it's no longer compact. Usually, when one says that a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is compact, it is meant that there does exist a compact lie group whose lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: If you are talking about the compact Lie Group $SU(2)$ (not its Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$), then the written claim is indeed correct. (By the Peter Weyl theorem, as you pointed out correctly).

Comment: In this case $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ (spanned by 2x2 matrices) is equipped with a group operation, matrix multiplication. Sorry, then of course it is non-compact, since it is unbounded, right? Sorry about the confusion, thanks for your time

Comment: It is unbouded indeed. No problem, happy to help!

Comment: But isn't $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ the space of (traceless) skew herimitan matrices? If you multiply two of them, the result is not skew hermitian in general (multiplication would be given by the lie bracket, but this is not associative and hence doesnt give a group operation)

Comment: So in this case because of Peter-Weyl theorem $SU(2)$ has finite dimensional irreducible representations which can be lifted to its Lie-Algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ (of 2x2 matrices) by Lie's second theorem

Comment: They can be ''liftet'' regardless of Lie's second theorem. Every representation of a Lie Group induces a representation of it's Lie Algebra. The critical point is wether every representation of the given Lie Algebra is of this form.
Edit: We should move this discussion to chat, or you should ask a new question (I don't think the comment section is appropriate for such lenghty discussions...)